# wxpython: how to show and hide one shape with button

Tags: wxpython

Hello I am trying to create an on off button and two circles,the one circle is white and the other one red,the circles represent one LED,when I press on I want to see the red circle and wenn I press again see the white. I have write this code but I dont wont to work it with two panels and call the on switch panels function.Is any other way to do that?I mean if I can bind the on button with the red circle and hide the white and when I press again the same button or another one with the label off to hide the red and show the white?

Here is the code:

```
`import wx

class PanelOne(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        button =wx.Button(self, label="Turn ON", pos=(160, 130))
        button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, parent.onSwitchPanels)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)

    def OnPaint(self, evt):
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        dc.Clear() 
        dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush('White'))
        dc.DrawCircle(200, 230, 35)


class PanelTwo(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        button =wx.Button(self, label="Turn OFF", pos=(160, 130))
        button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, parent.onSwitchPanels)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)

    def OnPaint(self, evt):
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        dc.Clear() 
        dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush('Red'))
        dc.DrawCircle(200, 230, 35)


class MainForm(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY,"LED" )

        self.panel_one = PanelOne(self)
        self.panel_two = PanelTwo(self)
        self.panel_two.Hide()

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.panel_one, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.sizer.Add(self.panel_two, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)


    def onSwitchPanels(self, event):
        if self.panel_one.IsShown():
            self.SetTitle("LED")
            self.panel_one.Hide()
            self.panel_two.Show()
        else:
            self.SetTitle("LED")
            self.panel_one.Show()
            self.panel_two.Hide()
        self.Layout()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainForm()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way using a single panel that alters the same button and same circle.

```
import wx


class PanelOne(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.state = [('White', 'Turn ON'), ('Red', 'Turn OFF')]
        self.button = wx.Button(self, label=self.state[0][1], pos=(160, 130))
        self.button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.switch_state)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)

    def OnPaint(self, evt):
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        dc.Clear()
        dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush(self.state[0][0]))
        dc.DrawCircle(200, 230, 35)

    def switch_state(self, event):
        self.state.append(self.state.pop(0))
        self.button.SetLabel(label=self.state[0][1])
        self.Refresh()


class MainForm(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "LED")
        self.panel_one = PanelOne(self)
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.panel_one, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainForm()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```